# MySql and parallel execution of command in writing from more users

Tags: mysql, sql, locking

I have InnoDB tables in Mysql, and I would know if when I exec an `UPDATE` my database automatically guarantees a lock or not.

I clarify the concept further:
I have multiple concurrent access to a database i.e. the scenario is that I have more users that access in writing in the same time the same record of a table. For example an UPDATE that modify the amount of available t-shirts (2 users in the same time decrease this amount).   Sql database guarantees atomicity  of an UPDATE query (and other queries) and lock of record(or table)? (Because if the UPDATE queries can be "scheduled" you could have a wrong result).

And if the built-in behavior does not assure me,  how do you set it up to ensure serial execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Innodb will auto acquire locks when executing write sql (like update, delete or locking read), you could see MySQL documents [Locks Set by Different SQL Statements in InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html) for more details

And moreover, MySQL support atomic update (via locking), but the real result based on your sqls. In your case, the below sql could ensure the final result is expected even when multiple threads execute concurrently

```sql
UPDATE table_xxx SET t_shirts_count = t_shirts_count + 1 
WHERE ...
```

However, this one is not (select-increment-update) even if the update itself is atomic, but the entire process is not atomic

```sql
SELECT t_shirts_count FROM table_xxx WHERE ...

-- increment `t_shirts_count` in application code (not in DB)

UPDATE table_xxx set t_shirts_count = new_t_shirts_count WHERE...
```

By the way, if the above atomic update does not meet you, try [Locking Read](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html), `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE` or `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` (suppose that you are using MySQL 5.7, the syntax would be a little different in MySQL 8.0)